# Best way to initialize class fields

Tags: java, reflection

what is the best way to initialize class fields when there are several needs with reflection? It is better to create an initialize method or put everything in the same constructor, below I have put 2 examples, which is the best way?

```
public House(String name) {
     this.name = name ;
     prices = new HashMap<>();
     initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    try {
        Object func = Class.forName("network.game.engine.ExpansionsFunction").invoke(name);
        houseProfile = Main.GET_FUNCTION_METHOD.invoke(func);
        houseMap = Main.HOUSE_MAP_METHOD.invoke(houseProfile);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e.getCause());
    }
}

public House(String name) {
     this.name = name ;
     prices = new HashMap<>();
     try {
         Object func = Class.forName("network.game.engine.ExpansionsFunction").invoke(name);
         houseProfile = Main.GET_FUNCTION_METHOD.invoke(func);
         houseMap = Main.HOUSE_MAP_METHOD.invoke(houseProfile);
     } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
         throw new IllegalStateException(e.getCause());
     }
}
```

Comment: The best question here is, why do you need to initialize that class using reflection in order to invoke one of its methods?

Comment: @akortex i need to use reflection i dont have access to the library, also the question is not this, do not answer if your question does not contribute

Comment: Your question lacks in both information as well as the general description regarding your problem. The reason for the comment was to clarify what was not included in the first place. So continuing, what do you mean by saying you do not have access to the library?

Comment: You have tagged the question with `[reflection]` and are showing a code example with Reflection. If your question is not Reflection-specific, don’t tag your question as such and generally, remove irrelevant things from your code example.

Comment: What is the point of having an `initialize` method?